# Center table in the page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Having this example (note the use of `tufte-handout` document class):

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,nohyper]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage[]{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\centerline{\Large\bf A title here}

\lipsum[2]

\bigskip{}

% Auto-generated ------------------------------------------
\begin{longtable}{r|lr|r}
  \hline
mpg & cyl & disp & hp \\ 
  \hline
21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 \\ 
  21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 \\ 
  22.80 & 4.00 & 108.00 & 93.00 \\ 
  21.40 & 6.00 & 258.00 & 110.00 \\ 
  18.70 & 8.00 & 360.00 & 175.00 \\ 
  18.10 & 6.00 & 225.00 & 105.00 \\ 
  14.30 & 8.00 & 360.00 & 245.00 \\ 
  24.40 & 4.00 & 146.70 & 62.00 \\ 
  22.80 & 4.00 & 140.80 & 95.00 \\ 
  19.20 & 6.00 & 167.60 & 123.00 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\caption{Table caption.}
\end{longtable}
% Auto-generated ------------------------------------------

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The resulting output is like:

[image]

Is it possible to center the table with respect to the page? That would mean moving it to the right, even if it overtakes the margin. Moving it to the right a fixed distance without actually calculating the exact page center would be enough (i.e.: move the table 2.5cm to the right).

The table code would be auto-generated, so if there is a way to do so writing some code around it (without actually touching the table code), that would be great.

Comment: you can try `\begingroup\setlength{\hsize}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2in\relax} your tabular \endgroup`

Comment: @touhami: that works. Could you add it as an answer? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copied from a [very similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31522918/4707703), the following code should work:

```
\begin{fullwidth}
\makeatletter\setlength\hsize{\@tufte@fullwidth}\makeatother
...
\end{fullwidth}
```

Answer (score 4):

One possibility using a `\makebox` and a `minipage` (which means no page breaks are allowed now):

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english,nohyper,draft]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage[]{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}

\centerline{\Large\bf A title here}

\lipsum[2]

\bigskip{}

% Auto-generated ------------------------------------------
\noindent\hspace*{-\dimexpr\oddsidemargin+1in\relax}\makebox[\paperwidth]{\begin{minipage}{\paperwidth}%
\begin{longtable}{r|lr|r}
  \hline
mpg & cyl & disp & hp \\ 
  \hline
21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 \\ 
  21.00 & 6.00 & 160.00 & 110.00 \\ 
  22.80 & 4.00 & 108.00 & 93.00 \\ 
  21.40 & 6.00 & 258.00 & 110.00 \\ 
  18.70 & 8.00 & 360.00 & 175.00 \\ 
  18.10 & 6.00 & 225.00 & 105.00 \\ 
  14.30 & 8.00 & 360.00 & 245.00 \\ 
  24.40 & 4.00 & 146.70 & 62.00 \\ 
  22.80 & 4.00 & 140.80 & 95.00 \\ 
  19.20 & 6.00 & 167.60 & 123.00 \\ 
   \hline
\hline
\caption{Table caption.}
\end{longtable}%
% Auto-generated ------------------------------------------
\end{minipage}}\hspace*{-\paperwidth}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```